# MySQL Load data infile -- double quotes in a double quoted value as "a "double" quoted value"

Tags: mysql, csv, double-quotes, load-data-infile

I have a csv file with millions of rows. Here is the command I am using to load data

```
load data local infile 'myfile' into table test.mytable
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines
```

This caters almost everything except some of the lines where there are double quotes inside a double quoted string. as in

```
"first column",second column,"third column has "double quotes" inside", fourth column
```

It truncates the third column and give me warning as this row does not contain data for all columns.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV is broken. There is no way MySQL or any program can import it. The double quotes needed to be escaped if inside a column.

You might fix the CSV with a script. If the quotes doesn't have a comma in front or behind it, it's probably part of the text and should be escaped.

The following regular expression will do a [negative lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find quotes that don't have a quote right in front or behind it.

```
/(?<!^)(?<!,)(\s*)"(\s*)(?!,)(?!$)/
```

### [See it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qcE8FS/1)

---

On the command like you can run

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!,)(?<!^)(\s*)"(\s*)(?!,)(?!$)/\1\\"\2/g' data.csv > data-fixed.csv
```

---

***Note that this method isn't fool proof. If there is a double quote that does have a comma behind it but is part of the text, there is little you can do to fix the CSV. In that case, the script simply has no way of knowing if it's a column delimiter or not.***

Comment: This is something that came into my mind too. Thanks for the perl command :)

Comment: @RohailAbbas Glad I could help. If your question is answered, please mark it as such by pressing the check mark under the up/down vote.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv`